# When using the 'isin' function in the data frame condition filtering, can filtering be performed including overlapping data?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

After importing 10 samples from a specific column, we try to convert only those samples into 'object' -> 'int'. But when making a sample, it's definitely 10, but when filtered by the 'isin' function, it becomes 9. What's the reason? In addition, is there a way to filter 10 as they are?

```
url = 'https://ds-lecture-data.s3.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com/seoul_tree/seoul_tree.txt'
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv(url,sep='\t',skiprows=1)

np.random.seed(123)
df1 = df[~df['자치구'].isin(['서울시','공원녹지사업소','시설관리공단'])]
sampling = np.random.choice(df1['이팝나무'], size = 10) # <- 10 are made in this part
df2 = df1[df1['이팝나무'].isin(sampling)]['이팝나무'].str.replace(',' , '') # suddenly changed to 9
```

Comment: sampling isn't pulling all unique numbers. at least every run seems to have at least one duplicate so sampling is size 10, but you only get 9 rows b/c of 9 unique values

Comment: If so, is there a way to filter 10 as they are?

Comment: I suspect not easily. you'd have to first find out if you have values with more than 1 entry in sampling, then individually find them in df1 and append to the df2. time consuming, but that's how i think it could be done.

Comment: is random, but unique not an option?

Comment: I get the point. df[bla] == blah1 & df[bla] == blah2 like this, right?